# Is it possible to get card brand from payment element

Tags: stripe-payments

So I am using Stripe-Js [Payment elements](https://stripe.com/docs/js/element/payment_element) and need to get the card brand *(e.g visa, mastercard)*

But it seems that **brand** is only available on **cardElement's** `onChange`. I only get the payment method type when onChange is triggered

```
paymentElement.on('change', function(event) {
  // event.brand 
});
```

Now I know I could get the brand details if I do **confirmPayment** but I need this brand first before doing a payment due to some business-related logic that needs to be done before placing the payment.

Is there a way to get the card brand of what user entered before doing `confirmPayment` using Payment Elements?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Payment Element does not return card brand in any event of StripeJS. This is only possible in Card Element with `onChange` event as you mentioned.

Another possible way in Payment Element is to go with [server-side confirmation](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/finalize-payments-on-the-server) instead of using client-side confirmation. At step 6 of the [doc](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/finalize-payments-on-the-server), make an extra call to [PaymentMethod Retrieval API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/retrieve) to get card information including card brands from the PaymentMethod ID (`pm_xxx`) in the response of `stripe.updatePaymentIntent`. After checking the card brand, then make a PaymentIntent confirmation call at the server.

Please note that sign up is required to use server-side confirmation since it is currently in beta.

Comment: Thanks mate! One possible other solution I think off is using the `createPaymentMethod` on client side, but that doesnt seem to work on Paymentelement either so either I need to create  my own fields using Other Elements or just flag this as impossible to do.